# Why does this work in jsfiddle but not in my document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a wonderful jsfiddle that someone has made and wanted to use part of it in my project:

http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/29gtu/

It works on the jsfiddle but not in my HTML document. Here is what in my document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script>

$("button").click(function() {
    var id = $("#id").val();
    var text = "icon-"+id;
    // update the result array
    var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result"));
    if(result == null)
        result = [];

    result.push({id: id, icon: text});
    // save the new result array
    localStorage.setItem("result", JSON.stringify(result));

    // append the new li
    $("#bxs").append($("<li></li>").attr("id", "item-"+id).html(text));
});

// on init fill the ul
var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result"));
if(result != null) {
    for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
        var item = result[i];
        $("#bxs").append($("<li></li>").attr("id", "item-"+item.id).html(item.icon));
    }
}​

</script>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="bxs" class="tabs"> 
</ul>

<input type="text" id="id" /><button>save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is copied and pasted from the fiddle. I think it has to do with me not having a plugin for local storage. 
For that jsfiddle to work, do I need some external plugin that I am missing?

Comment: If you have a look at the right hand side of jsFiddle, you see that your code is executed `onLoad`, i.e. after the DOM and all resources loaded. That's not the case in the code you posted here. From the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Hello_jQuery) *"[...] As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready. To do this, we register a ready event for the document. [...]"*. I recommend reading it :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should wrap your whole code within `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

So.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            var id = $("#id").val();
            var text = "icon-" + id;
            // update the result array
            var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result"));
            if (result == null) result = [];

            result.push({
                id: id,
                icon: text
            });
            // save the new result array
            localStorage.setItem("result", JSON.stringify(result));

            // append the new li
            $("#bxs").append($("<li></li>").attr("id", "item-" + id).html(text));
        });

        // on init fill the ul
        var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result"));
        if (result != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var item = result[i];
                $("#bxs").append($("<li></li>").attr("id", "item-" + item.id).html(item.icon));
            }
        }

    });

</script>
```

#### Note

In `jsfiddle` `onLoad` mode do that for you, i.e. when you select `onLoad` from left side panel drop down, then all js code execute after all resources become appeared in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Put in `$(document).ready` like this, Also give type of script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   

    $("button").click(function() {
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var text = "icon-" + id;
        // update the result array
        var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result"));
        if (result == null) result = [];

        result.push({
            id: id,
            icon: text
        });
        // save the new result array
        localStorage.setItem("result", JSON.stringify(result));

        // append the new li
        $("#bxs").append($("<li></li>").attr("id", "item-" + id).html(text));
    });

    // on init fill the ul
    var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result"));
    if (result != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var item = result[i];
            $("#bxs").append($("<li></li>").attr("id", "item-" + item.id).html(item.icon));
        }
    }
})​;    
 </script>
```