# Why is this simple code working on JSFiddle but not on my server?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that I am trying to get working. For some reason [it works fine on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mwqL/1/), but nothing happens when I type in the text box when the code is being served up from my server. Why might that be?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#userInput').keyup(function(){
            alert("key up");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="userInput" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870207/why-does-this-work-in-jsfiddle-but-not-in-my-document?rq=1

Comment: Have a look at the second select box on the right. It says "onLoad". As always, it's advised to read [the documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar) of the tool you are using ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be in dom ready

```
$(function(){
        $('#userInput').keyup(function(){
            alert("key up");
        });
});
```

In jsfiddle under the `Frameworks & Extensions` section in the second drop down `onload` will be selected by default, that means all the scripts in the script frame will get executed only after the entire dom is loaded.

But when we move that script to a page, we need to make use of [.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r6R6C/)
Demo: [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r6R6C/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Your script is attaching the keyup function to an element that doesn't exist yet. You need to either put your script at the bottom of your page, or use `$(document).ready(function(){//your code});`

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you need to wrap it in `.ready` function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userInput').keyup(function(){
        alert("key up");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JS code is executed before the DOM is ready. Put the JavaScript at the bottom or use jQuery `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#userInput').keyup(function(){
            alert("key up");
     });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="userInput" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```