# a jQuery code is working on jsFiddle but not at home

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I really don't get why this jQuery code :

```
boxStop = function() {
    var box = $('.box:last');
    box.stop().slideToggle(150, function() {
        box.remove();
    });
}


$(document).on('mouseover', '.test', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $('body').append('<div class="box"></div>');
    var box = $('.box:last');
    var posTop = el.offset().top;
    var posLeft = el.offset().left;
    box.hide().css({
        'left': posLeft,
        'top': posTop
    }).html('azerty<br>azerty<br>azerty<br>azerty<br>azerty<br>azerty<br>azerty').slideToggle(150);
}).on('mouseout', '.test', function() {
    if (!$('.box').is(':hover')){boxStop();}
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '.box', function() {
        boxStop();
});
```

is working on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/VECEJ/

but on my computer when the mouse goes from .test to .box, .box slideToggle instead of staying.

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to. If there are no errors, the problem is that jsfiddle wraps the JS code automatically to a document ready event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this work in jsfiddle but not in my document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870207/why-does-this-work-in-jsfiddle-but-not-in-my-document)

Comment: That's a pretty cool effect.

Comment: Silly question, but are you including the jsquery js at home?

Comment: @Juhana there is no error, so what should I do to have the same effect as jsfiddle?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Juhana but I already wrap my code with $(document).ready(function() {